# qt inherited signal won't reach to slot

Tags: qt, inheritance, signals-slots, multithreading

here's the code of my problem

```
class Base : QThread  
{
   Q_OBJECT  
 virtual void run() = 0;  
signals:  
 void Ping(int);  
};  

class Derived : public Base  
{  
  void run()  
  {  
    emit Ping(42);  
  }  
}
```

the signal(42) won't reach/call to slots. what's wrong?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did that 100 times, it does work. Are you sure your base class is properly MOC'ed ? (i.e. defined in a file contained in HEADERS section of `.pro`) Also when connecting your signal, check the return status of `QObject::connect` (it's a boolean). A good practice is something like that

```
bool r=false;
r=QObject::connect(pObj1,SIGNAL(signalStuff()),pObj2,SLOT(gotStuff()));
Q_ASSERT(r);
```

As Liz noticed, if something went wrong in your `connect`, you can check the traces to know what happened.

I can also note :

- you don't have to redefine `run` in your base class, it's already defined by [QThread](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qthread.html#run)
- Common pitfall with `QThread`: Base class and Derived class belong to the thread which created them, not in the newly created thread
- you don't connect your signal to any slot in your sample, so it won't trigger anything (I suppose it's done elsewhere)
- your class Derived lacks the final `;`

**EDIT**:

Edited to take into account liz' interesting comment.

Comment: (Not worth a separate answer) Check the output of your program.  If there is a problem with the connect call, Qt dumps an error to the console window.  Sometimes it's as simple as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I came upon the same problem but managed to find solution. The problem in my case wasnt the inheritance (even tho i did emit from derived class).

The problem was the code calling emit signal was execute BEFORE the code connecting signal with slot. Therefor both signal was emitted and signal-slot connection worked fine, but the code in the slot wasnt executed because emit happened before connecting the slot to signal.

Maybe that helps someone in the future.